How to fix commenting out my code, I can't use "//" in my code and it is commenting out my code automatically
this is my code and i can't use "//" in url part because it comment out my code
<x-mail::message>
# Introduction

The body of your message.

<x-mail::button :url="https://youtu.be/-RJSbO8UZVY?si=dcXjvd0oK6Dwj46O" color="error">
Button Text
</x-mail::button>

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
</x-mail::message>

I try using "\" but it didn't work

When you set a property on a blade component prefixed with a colon, the value you set has to be PHP code. This means it could be a variable or a string.
You could try to set the url as a variable and pass that to the :url property, or surround the url by single quotes. e.g.
:url="$url"

Alternatively, removing the colon prefix from the property definition makes it so you can just pass a string to the component.
url="https://your.url/"

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade#passing-data-to-components
